# How to add column with default string

Tags: sql-server, default, alter-table

I am trying to update a table by adding a `nvarchar` column to it, and set it to a default value of string.Running the query does not set the default to my target string, but to `NULL`.

**Query**

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Files' AND COLUMN_NAME='CreatedIn') 
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Files ADD CreatedIn [nvarchar](10) default 'pm'
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE Files SET CreatedIn = "pm" '; 
END
```

I am expecting the column `CreatedIn` to be set for all rows to `"pm"`.However it remains null.

Answer (score 2):

Two changes:

```
-- 1. need NOT NULL here (and always use N prefix for Unicode literals)

ALTER TABLE Files ADD CreatedIn [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL default N'pm';

-- 2. need to double-up single quotes here, not use double quotes
--    double quotes are used to denote identifiers

EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE Files SET CreatedIn = N''pm'';';
```

However, the second statement should no longer be necessary. In its current form, it should have failed outright, unless there is a compatible column named `pm`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
WITH VALUES
```

Comment: Hi Ajay, thanks for the contribution. Do you mind explaining your response, and adding expanding it with an example based on the question asked? Links to the source of the answer are also highly encouraged.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide some context or an explanation on why this answers to the OP's question?